# how hard is to join to the security team on big tech?

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process, tech-industry

I have always been asking  myself , how hard is to join to the most elite team on big tech such as google , twitter , vmware , facebook , amazon . I have done multiples interviews on big tech such as 2 times on facebook, 1 google , and 1 amazon, but I think I am doing something wrong because I cannot go beyond the first interview.

I have multiples security roles , but I also hold OSCP / and MITRE ATT&CK knowledge , but however I am based on mexico city

CTF player , and security research CVE recreation  1.5 years

Ethical hacker 1 year PwC # workable experience

Penetration Tester 1.2 years # internships

security programmer  3 months # internships

Web Programmer 2 months # internships

if anyone could give me a guidance about it, I will be glad

Comment: of course , but what is the % of the probability to join on one of the well-known companies?

Comment: Given your post, it may also be related to your language skills...

Comment: hi @yesii_0691 !   Are you trying to get a job *in Mexico City* or *in the US* or *in Europe*?  Please let us know!

Comment: Just BTW.  I would urge you to use correct capitalization (so, "How hard.." not "how hard",  "Amazon" not "amazon" etc) every single time you write anything (every time!) if you want to work at Google etc.

Answer (score 4):

If I had to hazard a guess, I'd say it's probably your lack of experience. 2 months, 3 months, 1 year, etc. This is not an experience level that would likely get you a dedicated security role at even a small company. This is not meant to discourage you or to to say that you shouldn't keep trying. Keep working on getting experience and education and keep trying, but I wouldn't expect any real breakthrough until you've built up a body of longer term experience.